# Overlay in Excel Services Chart

Tags: excel-services, chart

I have a chart in an Excel document that I am displaying on a Web Part page.
In Excel, I was able to draw a text box and overlay a percentage. However, these types of objects are not supported by Excel Services. Is there another way to achieve this?

It's a simple data series (shown below), and the percentage I want to display is in cell B2 (69).

```
Pie Donut
25  69
50  1
25  110
100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not already have a Title on your chart.. you can add a Title and format it to dynamically equal the desired cell's value and drag the "title" anywhere on the chart you need it to be!  Same for an Axis Title.